# Spotipy 401 / 405 No token provided

Tags: python, http, token, spotify, spotipy

I have been working on a [Spotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotify) / *[Spotipy](https://spotipy.readthedocs.io/)* application which will add the current song to a certain playlist.
My functions for getting the current song and showing a playlist are all doing fine. My function for adding a song to a playlist is not.

I am getting the following error in my IDE:

> http status: 405, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/myUserID/playlists/myPlayListID/tracks: 
> error

When I copy paste the link to the browser, I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "status": 401,
    "message": "No token provided"
  }
}
```

As far as I'm aware I'm providing a token.

Here is my function which makes the Spotify object

```
def __createSpotifyObject(self):
    """Will create a Spotify object and return it"""

    # Defining the scope(s) of the application
    scope = "playlist-modify-public playlist-modify-private user-read-currently-playing"

    # Getting the token
    token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username=USER_NAME, scope=scope, client_id=CLIENT_ID, client_secret=CLIENT_SECRET, redirect_uri="https://localhost/")

    # Returning our Spotify object
    return spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
```

Here is the function which tries to add a song to my playlist (this is where the error occurs)

I've tried catching the exception (which it did) and then trying to make a new Spotify object so it will refresh the token or something like that. It just gives me the same error.

```
def addCurrentSongToSelectedPlaylist(self):
    """Will add the currently playing song to the selected playlist"""

    # Checking if a playlist has been selected
    if (len(self.__selectedPlaylist ) < 1):

        print("No playlist selected")
        return

    # Getting the current song
    currentSong = self.getCurrentSong()

    # Adding the current song id to the selected playlist
    try:
        self.__spotify.user_playlist_add_tracks(USER, self.__selectedPlaylist, [currentSong["id"]])

    except spotipy.client.SpotifyException:
        # Re authenticating
        self.__spotify = self.__createSpotifyObject()
        self.__spotify.user_playlist_add_tracks(USER, self.__selectedPlaylist, [currentSong["id"]])
```

At this point the only thing I can think of is that the show playlist / show current playing song actions require fewer permissions, and that is why they work and the add song to playlist won't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out I implemented the user wrong. Instead of *username?si=someNumbers*, I needed to just enter the username.

- Copy and pasting the address of the error message in to the browser is useless since it is an API call, and it will always give back 401: no token provided due to trying to access it without a token.
- I just stumbled across this beautiful list of what every error code means: *[Web API](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/)*. This doesn't just apply to the web API, but also to the Spotipy library. Check the error code in your IDE or editor against the list on this page.